# Why Would Someone Fuse With a Light Farungen?

Tags: magic, humans

Recap: Creatures of living elements, called Farungen, exist in this world, which is a medieval fantasy-type. Most Farungen keep to themselves in remote areas (Fire Farungen in volcanos, Ice Farungen in the arctic north, Plant Farungen in jungles, you get the idea right?). Light Farungen represent the light within us (ie. our spirits); they are manifestations of the positives light embodies.

However, Light Farungen are incomplete, or rather ineffective, without something for them to illuminate. For this reason, Light Farungen seek out living things to unite with, and in the process of fusion turn two beings into one new being. The result is a new creature that resembles the organism that was fused with, its physical and mental traits a hodgepodge of both the Farungen and the creature it consumed.

If this doesn't make sense, this is how cute, friendly magical creatures (like unicorns) and heroes are created. The Light of the Farungen infuses the body of its host, enhancing and transforming its physical, mental, and spiritual traits.

However, there are problems with this transformation; if someone undergoes this transformation, they lose all rights to normal life and are doomed to defend the realm from the evils besieging it. You ever heard "ignorance is bliss?" Well, for these heroes it's likely "lack of powers is bliss." If you've seen superheroes in comic books, or if you're well-acquainted with heroes like Link or Samus, you have the idea: stressful lifestyle, demanding job, very few breaks.

Furthermore, Dark Farungen are *drawn* to Light Farungen; they represent the void, while Light represents wholeness, so they seek out and attempt to beat down absorb any creature that's fused with a Light Farungen (such Light-infused organisms are immune to absorption until they are sufficiently weakened). Supervillains and monsters, animals or humans that have been absorbed by a Dark Farungen, are also drawn to heroes.

So, my question is **Why Would Someone Fuse With a Light Farungen?**

It's not as if it's a great job, any rewards they get will likely never make up for the demands constantly put upon them, and for the above drawbacks, I'm not sure "well, someone has to do it" will be the answer here. That would require an absolute *saint*, and those are hard to come by!

Comment: Why does anyone do anything? Given how complex human motivation is literally any reason could be valid.

Comment: seems like it give some benefit in enhancing the host physical, mental, and spiritual traits at least, the transformation maybe a plus (someone may like to be magical human) or acceptable cost for them to become hero.

Comment: Achievement unlocked. "Congratulations, you have just unlocks a new diamond trophy: "You lost me!".

Comment: "Why would a character do X?" isn't really about worldbuilding, it's about plot and character motivation.

Comment: Good point rek, sorry I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

## Low self esteem

Sometimes people have a bad image of themselves, and wish they were someone else. This includes a broad spectra of feelings and mental states ranging from discontent with body measurements to downright suicidal tendencies.

Fusing with a thingamajig is a way to take on a new identity and become someone else.

## For kicks

This gives you light powers? Lots of teenager fans of Star Wars, tabletop Dungeons and Dragons players and the random Legend of Korra would volunteer for this in order to become a jedi master/a light elemental/the next avatar.

## Light furries

This information is somehow missing in the help pages for World Building: if something exists, there will be porn based on it (rule #34). It follows that some people will wish to live out this fetish, and with enough perverts you will eventually see them making conventions about it. I imagine that a lot of people would fuse with being of light just to satisfy their deepest fantasies.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is a continuation of the list made by The Square-Cube Law

### The Hero complex

Some people want to be a hero. It doesn't matter if it is a bad job, they will want to do the hero thing. There is a lot of reasons for this (escape from life, thirst for power or just doing the right thing).

### The Soldier factor

The fact is lots of people become soldiers, and that doesn't sound like a great job to most. However if the pitch was made patriotically, or the negatives are downplayed then perhaps you will get a lot of takers

### Desperation (The Katniss effect)

If people are poor or don't have a lot of options, and the likely fate for them is an early death in harsh conditions, then you will get a lot of takers if it means that they can live well for a few years, or if their family can live well because of their sacrifice.
Think Katniss from The hunger games

Comment: For the soldier factor, if the fusion gives any combat advantages at all you can expect platoons of light fusions to be a thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Second Chance at Life**

In keeping with the light Farungen's extreme altruism, they don't enjoy the loss of identity experienced by their host. They prefer to fuse with people  who would otherwise have either a short of miserable life.

Their favourite hosts are people who either (a) lost a limb and are slowly dying from infection or (b) suffer extreme PTSD from a battle for example. Both these types of people are considered *incomplete* and the Farungen wants to help them.

The fusion restores the body to tip-top condition and goes a long way to heal mental illness. This is not so great as it sounds, however, since the mentally ill bits of the mind are not healed so much as lobotomised and replaced with bits the Farungen's mind.

If your son goes to the shops and comes back as a light Farungen then you have suddenly lost your son, which is heartbreaking. It's slightly easier to deal with if your son instead goes to war and comes back as a light Farungen. Then the alternative is him dying in battle.

Answer (score 1):

Why would anyone become a paladin/soldier/guard?

So others don’t have to.

The people of this realm know that the Dark Farungen will destroy everything they hold dear. They’ve seen monsters, and they can’t stand the thought of their family falling prey to them.

So they choose to stand and fight the darkness. They do this even if there is no light Farungen, knowing that only selfless dedication to defending the realm will keep their friends and family safe. Vanilla mortals set their feet, draw a line in the sand and say ‘No further’ to the horrors created by the Dark Farungen. Most of them will die, since they’re overmatched in power, but they would rather give themselves than see any of their kin come to harm.

In such a setting the opportunity to merge with a Light Farungen is an honour. Your heroes have already dedicated themselves to an awful (and short) life in defence of the realm.  Why not do it with a bit of help? Level the playing field. Perhaps keep some of your comrades in arms from dying horrible deaths. The kind of people who selflessly put themselves in harms way, knowing the cost but choosing to do it anyway? They’re exactly the kind of people a light Farungen would want to bond with.

I’d argue that “well, someone has to do it” is not only a perfectly valid answer, it’s the answer that comes naturally from the idea of light/dark existing. Evil creatures will always bond with Dark Farungen, so someone does have to do it. They’ll have to do it even if there’s no spirit of goodness giving them superpowers, and the people who would do it even without power are the ones most deserving of wielding it.